# I need help to install the chere package

Tags: cygwin

I have installed Cygwin.  I need the chere package but it was not in the Shells category at time of install.  Where is it now?  Or how can I get this?

Answer (score 5):

The `chere` package is shown as an available package in the [Cygwin package list](http://cygwin.com/packages/).  There's at least a couple options here.

**Option 1:**

Try out `apt-cyg`, available [here](https://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/).

**Option 2:**

1. Run the Cygwin setup file (if you didn't save your setup executable, pick the appropriate file [here](http://cygwin.com/install.html)).
2. Choose the `Install from Internet` option.
3. Select the same Root Install directory you previously used.
4. Choose a local package directory.  You might consider choosing a different install files directory than previously (or backing it up), as if you choose a different internet source, your install files may get wiped out, if that matters to you.
5. Select an internet source.
6. In `Select Packages`, select the radio button for `Keep`, if you don't want to modify your existing files unnecessarily.
7. Type `chere` in to the Search box and select it.
8. Proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the packages on cygwin.com.  32 bit packages seems to be available 15th Sept 2013, but not 64 bit.

**32 bit** (http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=chere&arch=x86):

```
x86/chere/chere-1.1-1   
x86/chere/chere-1.2-1   
x86/fontconfig-doc/fontconfig-doc-2.10.93-1
```

**64 bit** (http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=chere&arch=x86_64):

```
x86_64/fontconfig-doc/fontconfig-doc-2.10.93-1
```

Note that the fontconfig is a false positive match.